# How to make sure my API data is not undefined with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

So I'm using react with ts and redux, and I have a reducer which gets movies on a certain page. Then I have a selector and setState with movies. I add the results of a call from the selector to the movies state. Overall it looks like this:

```
const playing = useSelector(selectPlaying);
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
```

Use effect function:

```
useEffect(() =>{
        if(fetching){
          console.log('fetching');
            dispatch(fetchPlaying(currentPage));
            setMovies([...movies, ...playing?.results!]);
            setCurrentPage(prevState => prevState + 1);
            setTotalCount(playing?.total_results!);
        }
  }, [fetching])
```

Rendering movies:

```
{movies.length > 0 ?
                movies.map((movie) =>
                    <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}><MovieItem movie={movie}/></Link>
                )
                :
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
              }
```

Most of the times it works fine and I get movies from an API, but sometimes I guess the dispatch function is late, and `playing.results` can be undefined, and I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property Symbol.iterator of undefined
```

So I want to always make sure that `playing` is not undefined before calling a function. I tried adding `if(playing)...` inside of a useEffect, but in that case the `movies` array is just empty and data doesn't load on the page.

Edit:
Also the problem is: when I open that page from the main page, everything works fine, but if I refresh the page it happens again. Maybe `dispatch` works only once?

Comment: Does it work when you replace `setMovies([...movies, ...playing?.results!])` with `setMovies([...movies, ...(playing?.results ?? [])])`?

Comment: hi! i used it, and it works from time to time, but if `playing?.results` is still empty the movies is empty too, and the page doesn't display anything, how could i make it wait till `playing.results` is there and then call `setMovies`?

Comment: where is the ```playing``` state defined? I've run into this problem before when I tried to render a component before I knew that the state from redux exists. If that's the case, just conditionally render your component once ```playing``` exists in redux.

Comment: The dispatch function can't be "late", there is probably something you overlooked in your async flow. Shouldn't the linter complain that `playing` is not listed as a dependency of the hook btw?